# Convert numbers into letters and multiply the number by itself

Tags: c++

Sample Input #2

```
8
5
12
12
15
23
15
18
12
4
```

Sample Output #2

```
helloworld

8:8-16-24-32-40-48-56-64

5:5-10-15-20-25

12:12-24-36-48-60-72-84-96-108-120-132-144

12:12-24-36-48-60-72-84-96-108-120-132-144

15:15-30-45-60-75-90-105-120-135-150-165-180-195-210-225

23:23-46-69-92-115-138-161-184-207-230-253-276-299-322-345-368-391-414-437-460-483-506-529

15:15-30-45-60-75-90-105-120-135-150-165-180-195-210-225

18:18-36-54-72-90-108-126-144-162-180-198-216-234-252-270-288-306-324

12:12-24-36-48-60-72-84-96-108-120-132-144

4:4-8-12-16
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

char secretCode(char number)
{
    if(number >= 1 && number <= 26)
    {
        return static_cast<char>('a' - 1 + number);
    }
    else if (number >= 27 && number <= 52)
    {
        return static_cast<char>('a' - 27 + number);
    }
    else if (number >= 53 && number <= 104)
    {
        return static_cast<char>('a' - 53 + number);
    }
}

void printSequence(int number[10])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << secretCode(number[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number[10];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
    {
        cin >> number[x];
        printSequence(number);
        for (int y = number[x]; y <= number[x]; ++y)
        {
            for (int z = 1; z <= number[x]; ++z)
            {
                if (z > 1)
                {
                    cout << "-";
                }

                if (z < 1)
                {
                    cout << number[x] * -1;
                }
                else
                    cout << number[x] * z ;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I think I got the answer but I'm doing something wrong in my code, I'm pretty new to programming still and have been doing fine so far till I encounter the loop and functions..

Comment: why do you think there is something wrong in your code?

Comment: I think I need to put the loop I have on my Int main() somewhere else but I haven't been able to think on how to do that.

Comment: `'a'-'z'` is not guaranteed to be contiguous (and it is not for EBCDIC).

Comment: The 10 numbers will then be decoded according to character equivalent in the English alphabet. Example:
1 = a
2 = b
26 = z.

However, this doesn't mean that the program will only evaluate from 1 to 26. Example:
26 = z
52 = z
104 = z.
That's why I made my char secretCode() like that

Comment: split input and output: End the loop after `cin >> number[x];`, Then think when you need a loop, and when not.

Comment: `for(int y=number[x]; y<=number[x]; ++y)` is done exactly once, so can be removed.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do the past hour but I haven't been able to think of anything so far, I posted my code like that since it's the closest to the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
char secretCode(char number)
{
    if(number >= 1 && number <= 26)
    {
        return static_cast<char>('a' - 1 + number);
    }
        else if (number >= 27 && number <= 52)
    {
        return static_cast<char>('a' - 27 + number);
    }
        else if (number >= 53 && number <= 104)
    {
        return static_cast<char>('a' - 53 + number);
    }
}

void printSequence(int number[10])
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout << secretCode(number[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    int len = 0;
    while(len < 10){
        cout << number[len] << ":";
        for(int z=1; z<=number[len]; ++z){
             if (z>1)
            {
                cout << "-";
            }
            if (z<1)
            {
                cout <<number[len];
            }
            else
            cout << number[len]*z ;
        }
        cout << endl;
        len += 1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int number[10];
    for(int x=0; x<10; ++x)
    {
        cin >> number[x];
    }
    printSequence(number);
}
```